# ZK MVVM Validation - Dependent Property Array content?

Tags: java, zk

I'm playing around with the ZK 8 MVVM form validation system and generally it seems to do what I want, but I wonder what the definition of the dependent property index is...

Let's take a simple validator...

```
public class FormValidator extends AbstractValidator {

    @Override
    public void validate(final ValidationContext ctx) {

        Property[] properties = ctx.getProperties("firstName");

        Object value0 = properties[0].getValue();
        Object value1 = properties[1].getValue();

    }
}
```

So, when this is called before the save command, for every property, I get a `Property[]` array of length 2. But somehow, I have yet to find out what is stored in `[0]` and what is stored in `[1]`. Sometimes it seems that `[0]` stores the current value (which may or may not be valid according the field validator there) and `[1]` the last valid entry... But sometimes it seems to be the other way round...

The examples in the [documentation](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/data_binding/validator.html) always seem to simply take the first element (`[0]`) for validation, but I would like the understand what both parts of this pair actually mean...

Anyone got an idea for that?

Comment: Which kind of field are you trying to validate? datebox, textbox, other...

Comment: My test case was a simple form with two textboxes (firstName, lastName) and a save button with the 'save' command on it and the typical form validation before 'save'. When the form validator is used, for each of the two textboxes, I get an array of Property with length == 2. I want to know what the meaning of [0] and [1] is.

Answer (score 0):

I might be off the mark with my answer, but if you are using ZK8, you should look into using [Form binding](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/data_binding/form_binding.html)

That way you do not have to handle Properties in your validator and can retrieve a proxy object matching the bean you use for your form.
If you are using a User POJO with a firstName and lastName attribut.

```
User myProxy= (User ) ctx.getProperty().getValue();
```

And then you can validate both fields by simply doing getFirstName and getLastName on myProxy.

Hope it helps.